# Can I do branch control with promoted type?

Tags: haskell

I create a toy program for trying to do branch on a promoted type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables, GADTs #-}
module Foo where

import Data.Proxy

data Out = ToInt | ToBool

type family F (a :: Out) where
    F ToInt = Int
    F ToBool = Bool

foo :: forall k. Proxy (k :: Out) -> Int -> F k
foo p = case p of
    (Proxy :: Proxy 'ToInt) -> id
    (Proxy :: Proxy 'ToBool) -> (== 0)
```

Here I tried to branch on `Proxy` and use explicit type signature on them, but this doesn't work, GHC complains:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Foo              ( Foo.hs, Foo.o )

Foo.hs:15:6: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘k’ with ‘'ToBool’
      ‘k’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          foo :: forall (k :: Out). Proxy k -> Int -> F k
        at Foo.hs:12:15
      Expected type: Proxy 'ToBool
        Actual type: Proxy k
    • When checking that the pattern signature: Proxy 'ToBool
        fits the type of its context: Proxy k
      In the pattern: Proxy :: Proxy ToBool
      In a case alternative: (Proxy :: Proxy ToBool) -> (== 0)
    • Relevant bindings include
        p :: Proxy k (bound at Foo.hs:13:5)
        foo :: Proxy k -> Int -> F k (bound at Foo.hs:13:1)
```

I think this basically says GHC have trouble figuring out `k ~ 'ToBool` on the second branch. (actually first branch doesn't work either for a very similar error message)

is this actually possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is impossible. Types are erased, so you can't use them directly to make decisions at run time. The usual approach is to replace the proxy with a singleton. In this case, I think the type family is overkill, so I've dropped it.

```
data Out a where
  ToInt :: Out Int
  ToBool :: Out Bool

foo :: forall k. Out k -> Int -> k
foo p = case p of
    ToInt -> id
    ToBool -> (== 0)
```

If you wanted, you could instead use `DataKinds` to promote your `Out` constructors and index a singleton type by those:

```
data OutS a where
  ToIntS :: OutS 'ToInt
  ToBoolS :: OutS 'ToBool

foo :: forall k. OutS k -> Int -> F k
foo p = case p of
   ToIntS -> id
   ToBoolS -> (== 0)
```

But in this case I'm not sure there's much of a point.

Another design option (which you can use with either of the above) is to tie a type to its singleton using a class:

```
class SConv t where
  sConv :: proxy t -> OutS t
instance SConv 'ToInt where
  sConv _ = ToIntS
instance SConv 'ToBool where
  sConv _ = ToBoolS
```

This makes the singleton passing a bit more implicit in some cases.

Hopefully, Richard Eisenberg will finish his `DependentHaskell` work within the next couple years, at which point all this will become much less painful.